# Getting recent posts based on category items in custom menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a tabbed navigation, each tab containing 5 recent post excerpts of category items that are listed in a custom menu.

I'm planning to load all these posts at once and put each category in its own tab. I know how to get posts and navigation links separately but not how to make them work together..

Thanks for your help!

Comment: any sample link, what you want to achieve?

Comment: @boom_Shiva please see http://blogs.cisco.com/. They use tabs for most recent, most commented and popular posts. I would like to use a custom menu for this with categories. Each tab contains 5 recent posts for each menu item. I prefer a custom menu to keep it flexible for my customer. Thanks!

Comment: You can get Most Populatr, Most Commented and Recent Post easily.
https://gist.github.com/UmeshSingla/public
Why you want it in a custom menu??
You can just make the widgets for each and include the widget if required.

Comment: Thanks @boom_Shiva, I've managed to solve it with AJAX. I will post the code tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I´ve managed to work around this by adding the WP category slug as a class to my menu items and to a container div on each one of my categories on my *recent posts per category* overview page.

I use AJAX to load the category container div into my *filter-content* div based on the menu item clicked.

```
$('.menu-item li').click(
        function () {                 
              //Category slug is the 5th class on my menu item
              var catName = jQuery(this)[0].className.split(' ')[4];
              //categories is my page url
              $('.filter-content').load('categories .' + catName);
   });
```

I hope someone will find this useful!